# JavaScript temperature converter gives Invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: javascript

I was working on a JavaScript function tonight following a tutorial that would convert fahrenheit to celsius.

I tried this way:

```
function fahrToCels(fahrTemp) {
  return (fahrTemp − 32) * (5⁄9);
}
console.log(fahrToCels(140));
```

and I got the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I researched the correct way to write this online and found similar code to mine such as:

```
function toCelsius(f) {
           return (5/9) * (f-32);
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius(77);
```

I tried running this and I did not get an error. But, I couldn't figure out why my way was wrong, so when I gave up and looked up the answer they were looking for, I found this:

```
function fahrToCels(fahrTemp) {
  return (fahrTemp - 32) / 1.8;
}

console.log(fahrToCels(140));
```

This does not give an error although it gives a different answer.
So, what gives here? I have something similar above, except without the 1.8. I am unclear on what the syntax error is telling me. Pleas help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid characters: `−` and `5⁄9`.

Change to:

`-` and `5/9`.

Something like this:

```js
function fahrToCels(fahrTemp) {
  return (fahrTemp - 32) * (5/9);
}
console.log(fahrToCels(140));
```

Comment: Help me here, I had the same code and still got the error.

Comment: I understand your code works, but is it whitespace? What was the issue?

Comment: Ahh! I see the problem now, the minus symbol was not the correct character. This is what happens when you copy and paste from repl to a proper code editor. Thank you Danny.

Comment: Surely you copied that code from some website with a different character encoding, for example UTF-8 to ANSI. Although the characters are displayed in a similar way, they correspond to another. `-` not equals to `–`.